# make react navigation header layout behave the same on both iOS and android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

using react-navigation v6 and can't figure out how to make the header work as iOS on android.

[image]

On android the header seems like it rendered on top of component screen. I'm using `'pan'` as `softwareKeyboardLayoutMode` with expo.

> app.config.ts

```json
    android: {
      ...
      softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: 'pan',
    },
```

Comment: Have you considered not using the react navigation header and making your own Header Component? I find that to be more consistent.

Comment: I have considered it and tried out something but that still made it overlay. The thing is that is has worked and now i stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause `<Animated.View entering={FadeIn}>` that seems to mess up how react-navigation does layout

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3368

Rewrote all the animations to use `Animated` from `react-native`